# Discrete Logs and Generators Property

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

If given some $X$ that is $g^x$ and I want to find $x$ but cannot use $X$ directly does it follow that :

$X*g \equiv g^\left(x+1\right)$

$ DLog(X*g) = x+1$

Therefore $x = DLog(X*g) - 1$?

I tried it with, $g=2, x=3 => X = 8 = 2^3 (mod \ 11)$ and it works out that $DLog(X*g) = DLog(2^4 (mod \ 11)) = DLog(5) = 4$

And $4-1 = 3$ so i get back $x$

But when I try it with $g=2, x=9 => X = 2^9 (mod \ 11 ) = 6 $, $X*g = g^\left(10\right) (mod \ 11) \equiv g^0 (mod \ 11 ) \equiv 1 (mod \ 11)$

I get $DLog(1) = 0$ and $0-1 = -1 (mod \ 11) = 10. But I'm not so sure i'm doing the edge cases right, because with other numbers I've tried it works ( but I haven't gone through all of it yet).

Am I missing something with the edge case?

Thanks

Comment: The order of the the multiplicative group of the integers mod $11$ is $10$, not $11$, so you should have calculated $-1 \equiv 9 \bmod {10}$.